# Изменение кодировки у цифр

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Сохраняю число в файл, но нужно чтобы пользователь не знал его, поэтому хочу просто перевести его в другую кодировку. Сохраняю так:

```
[Scr writeToFile:pth atomically:YES encoding:Кодировка error:nil];
```

Какую указать кодировку чтобы оно перевело даже число?

Comment: Скажите, где вы нашли информацию о том, что в разных кодировках у чисел разные байтовые представления?

Comment: Ну мне надо просто сохранить число, но чтобы пользователь не знал его.

Comment: можете просто сдвиг сделать перед записью и обратный сдвиг после чтения

Comment: можно просто складывать с какой то неявной константой, которую хранить рядом (это может быть дата) или накладывать xor.

Comment: Можно шифровать, можно в http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC , вопрос в том, а зачем это нужно?

Тривиальный шифр все равно вскроют (при желании). Так что, не занимайтесь самообманом.

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит заморачиваться с кодировкой, шифруйте и все.

Среди простых алгоритмов можно [Шифр Цезаря](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F) взять. Ну или же вообще придумать самому перестановку, или бинарный сдвиг, или просто плюсануть/умножить на константу, а при считывании отнять/разделить.

Answer (score 1):

Если Src это экземпляр `NSString` и вас тревожит то, что ваше число при открытии файла видно всем кому не лень, и целью является всего лишь скрыть его от глаз широкой публики спрятав за символами кракозябров, то пишите не строковое представление числа а именно это число. А то есть `NSInteger (float, double, short на выбор) -> NSData -> file`. Пример:

```
NSInteger integer = [Scr integerValue];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&integer length:sizeof(integer)];
[data writeToFile:pth atomically:YES];
```

Это не спасет от определения числа более-менее ИТ-грамотным человеком, но от широкой публики оградит. Так что задача вроде как решена.

Comment: А как читать из файла и переводить обратно в число или строку?

Comment: NSInteger integer;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[data getBytes:&integer length:sizeof(integer)];